# Don't print $title on certain content types

Tags: 7, theming

How would you go about not printing $title on only the 'article' content type? Do i do this through theme-settings.php or page.tpl.php?

Here's a start, but I don't think I'm going in the best direction with this in the theme file.

```
if ( !empty($node) && $node->type == 'article') { }
else {
  print $title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a module for this:

[Exclude Node Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title)

> **Info**
>
> This module handles a very simple functionality, decide whatever to
>   exclude a node title from full node page or node teasers.
>
> It provides a checkbox on node-edit pages for easier exclusion.
>
> Also provides the option to hide all titles of a certain Content type.
>   From the administrative interface you can select a content type to
>   hide title for.

And if you have [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) installed then this article explains how to do it with that module:

[Hide “Page Title” quickly using Display Suite in Drupal 7](http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/hide-%E2%80%9Cpage-title%E2%80%9D-quickly-using-display-suite-drupal-7)

> This is something that is so simple to do, once you have figured out
>   the steps to get to the right little click boxes to appear. I wish
>   that it were more intuitive to find, but for all those who struggle
>   with “hiding” the page titles, Display Suite makes it really easy to
>   choose to hide the page title for a specific Content Type or for a
>   particular Node.

Answer (score 1):

`hook_preprocess_page()` and `hook_process_page()` have access to `$variables['node']`, which is set if the page is relative to a node. So you can use the following code.

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'article') {
    $variables['title'] = '';
  }
}
```

I would rather implement this in a module, but you can implement it in a theme too.

You need this code because [`template_process_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_page/7.x) contains the following one.

```
if (!isset($variables['title'])) {
  $variables['title'] = drupal_get_title();
}
```

If you don't set `$variables['title']` in `hook_preprocess_page()`, `template_process_page()`, which runs after it, will set it to the default page.
It is enough you set the title to an empty string.

The default template file for pages don't need any change, since it normally checks the title has been set, and print it in the case it was.

Keep in mind that, passing to Drupal 8, you will need to change the code, since:

- [Process functions have been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2038981)
- There was a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2035055) to replace preprocess functions with other hooks, but it has been closed as *won't fix*
- The [page title is a block](https://www.drupal.org/node/2476947)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this using drupal_set_title().

```
 function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'article'){
    drupal_set_title('');
  }
```

}

Comment: Something like this is what I was looking for, but it gives an internal server error. Using function mytheme_preprocess_html doesn't give an error, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please use unset($variables['title']); instant of drupal_set_title('');

Comment: This (below) doesn't do anything in theme-settings.php, and causes a 500 error in template.php. Any other ideas? Sorry I'm not very strong in php or programming in general. Thank you.

function include_always_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'article'){
    unset($variables['title']);
  }

Comment: You can create page tpl for your content type.For your content type tpl name is "page--article.tpl.php" then you can remove $title from your content type tpl.you can also use display suite and disable title from manage display.